# Monitoring progress of IPython map_async?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython

I would like to count the number of times a function `f` has been called by IPython's map_async (so I can monitor progress). I am attempting to do this by having `f` print out messages:

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
from time import sleep

def f(x):
    from time import sleep
    sleep(1)
    print x
    return x**2


c = Client()
view = c[:]

parallel_result = view.map_async(f, range(10))

while not parallel_result.ready():
    sleep(.5)
    print parallel_result.stdout
```

The result is:

```
['', '']
['', '']
['', '']
[u'0\n1', u'5\n6']
[u'0\n1', u'5\n6']
[u'0\n1\n2', u'5\n6\n7']
[u'0\n1\n2', u'5\n6\n7']
[u'0\n1\n2\n3', u'5\n6\n7\n8']
[u'0\n1\n2\n3', u'5\n6\n7\n8']
[u'0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n', u'5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n']
```

The output of `parallel_result.stdout` is cumulative, which is a problem if `f` needs to run millions of times. How can I clear the `parallel_result.stdout` after checking it so that I only get new output each time I check? (I tried `parallel_result.stdout=[]` after the print statement, but this seems to prevent anything from going into `parallel_result.stdout`).

Alternatively, is there a way I can have `f` increment a shared counter? Thanks in advance!